How to deploy atomically on Nginx+Php-fpm without losing requests?
During deployment I need to update a source code of my web PHP application (more files), but I don't want to lose ANY http requests. Old pending requests could be handled by new source code (let's not worry about compatibility).
I don't think a reload (USR2 signal) of the php-fpm service is sufficient (it's not possible to atomically swap the source code because opcache.revalidate_freq), it probably has to do:

php-fpm stop
source code update (mv command)
php-fpm start,

but in that case nginx doesn't wait for php-fpm to start and starts returning 503 to visitors.
Does anyone know a simple way how to deploy atomically and process 100% of requests?
I have a solution that might work (another server in nginx upstream waiting for php-fpm to start..., configure graceful php-fpm stop...) but it seems complicated.

"I need to change php-fpm source code" - why do you need to change the source code of PHP itself?

Sorry for the wrong wording, I meant the source code of my application in PHP.

Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it. I don't even get why all this is neccessary - I don't restart or reload fpm during deployments

If you only change the source code without stopping and restarting php-fpm and the source code is composed of multiple files, then there is a risk that in some small/large time (up to opcache.revalidate_freq) the application will work with part of the old code and part of the new code, right?

That depends on your Opcache settings. If you're using the defaults, then you're dealing with a window of 2 seconds, which is well within acceptable limits even for high-traffic applications. You can change this to 0 if you want Opcache to check timestamps on every request. It will still serve out of memory if the files haven't changed, so you still get the benefits of Opcache. What you're thinking of doing is almost certainly unnecessary, but if you absolutely must, look into a Blue-Green deployment.

Thanks for the new term for me (similar). I'll take a look at this. But I was imagining it somehow easier using nginx configuration. Nginx can buffer requests when the php-fpm port does not response. It would need to buffer even if there is no service on the port (during a php-fpm restart). 5 seconds would be enough (max. duration of our deploy, we also restart other services, for simplicity I didn't mention them). I guess I want too much and too easy :-). Thanks.

Check this answer. Also, when deploying your app updates, conside using the opcache_reset() function rather than increasing the Opcache revalidation frequency (here is an example, the site is in Russian, but it is only a bash script you'll need to look at).
